# This code broke on me all of a sudden

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I just asked a question beforehand where an AJAX request was not working. I got it working, and for some reason 5 minutes after it has stopped working. I even tried ctrl+z'ing to go back to the previous state of my document, however it still won't work.

I have a button that sends an AJAX request, when I click it, it even says that the XHR request succeeded. What does not work, however, is that I cannot create an "alert();" that works.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Click Me</button>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".btn").click(function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'scripts/script.php',
                            success: function(data) {
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
</script>
```

script.php:

```
echo "string";
```

I've tried placing this alert(); within different script tags within the document and it still won't work. The console says the XHR request succeeds, so that means that the AJAX request is succesfully calling. There are no errors in the console. Everything is in the correct directory, jQuery is succesfully installed etc. so how can there even be a problem? This exact code was working before, but now it broke on me all of a sudden for no reason

All help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT ***

This code will work on Firefox, but not Chrome. I figured that there must be a glitch in the browser. Why is this? How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: what problem you are having. I tried this code and it works with alert message

Comment: see the edit above ^

Comment: for me its works in chrome too.

Comment: it was definitely a browser glitch, i restarted chrome and it works now

Answer (score 0):

Chrome was glitching out, I tried it on Firefox and it worked. I restarted Chrome and it works now.